# View which users exist on a remote computer?

Tags: linux, users, remote

If I have the IP address of a computer running Linux is it possible to see which user accounts exist on that computer, without having to ssh into it first?

Comment: Now, wouldn't that make life so much easier for the bad guys?

Comment: Even if you can `ssh` into a system, that is not enough. You can investigate `/etc/passwd`, but if you cannot see how PAM is set up on the system you'll  be missing other user accounts added through `libnss-extrausers` or via LDAP etc

Comment: @Anthon that's what `getent passwd` is for....and is why `getent` should be used in scripts that need to check usernames. groupnames, etc instead of simply grepping the first field of `/etc/passwd`, `/etc/group` and so on.

Answer (score 1):

Nowadays, on a correctly-configured system there shouldn't be any way of determining this.

On a badly-configured system, you might see different behaviour when attempting to log in depending on whether the user you're trying to log in as exists or not. (Hopefully not in the messages returned, but perhaps in the timing of the responses.)

In the past, [`finger`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/finger) would have told you:

```
finger @host
```

But those days are long gone...